# upload files and images by active storage in rails 5.2 to Amazon-S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, amazon-s3, upload, rails-activestorage

Issue when upload file and images to amazon s3 by active storage

issue `` undefined method `upload' for nil:NilClass" ``

in local is working but when using it in server development is getting issue
`` undefined method `upload' for nil:NilClass ``

I am creating an app with Rails 5.2 API and using active storage 5.2.3 to upload images and files to s3.

My configuration:

in `config/environments/development.rb`:

`config.active_storage.service = :amazon`

in `config/storage.yml`:

```
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
  region: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :s3_region) %>
  bucket: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :bucket) %>
```

in models:

`has_one_attached :avatar`

or

`has_many_attached :images`

in controller:

`params.permit(:name, avatar)`

or

`params.permit(:name, images: [])`

Comment: Do you have `gem 'aws-sdk-s3', require: false` in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: Yes, add ```gem 'aws-sdk-s3`, require: false```

Comment: is there any other setup to do it